# Cannot print crosstab with RMarkdown for a pdf document

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I am trying to print a `proc_freq` table using the `flextable` package in R Markdown to create a PDF file. Here is the code I used:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
sapply(c('am', 'vs'), function(col) print(proc_freq(mtcars, col)))
```
````

However, when I compile the file, the tables do not appear in the PDF. Can anyone provide any insight into this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**print is not a function for knitr rendering.**

The following is a copy of the documentation https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html#looping-in-r-mardown-documents

#### Looping in R Mardown documents

Some codes do not trigger the `knitr::knit_print()` method. This is the case, for
example, of `for loop` inside a chunk R.

In this case, you can use `knitr::knit_child()` that will print the raw code
adapted to the output format. Chunk option `results` must be set to `asis`.

When using `knitr::knit_child()`, the LaTeX and HTML dependencies required to
render the content from the included file are automatically detected and
integrated into the parent document. This means that if your included file
contains elements that require specific LaTeX or HTML packages (this is the case
for 'flextable'), `knitr::knit_child()` will ensure that all these dependencies
are properly handled and included in the final document.

Note the old function `flextable_to_rmd()` does not directly handle LaTeX and
HTML dependencies and should not be used anymore.

Here is an illustration. We will need two files:

- the child document `child-loop.Rmd`

```
library(flextable)
proc_freq(mtcars, col)
```

- and the main document `rmd-print-loop.Rmd`.

````
---
title: blah blah
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flextable)
```

> this is how to print flextables in a loop in a R Markdown document

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
sapply(
  c('am', 'vs'),
  function(col) {
    knitr::knit_child(input = "child-loop.Rmd", envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
  }) |> 
  cat(sep = '\n')
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

You can write a special `render` function to deal with the list object of flextables where you can use `knitr::knit_expand` to expand the flextable object template `{{ tab }}` (which I think works in the same way as @DavidGohel explained using `knitr::knit_child` and a template child r-markdown file, but in this case you do not need to use a child template file explicitly)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
date: "2023-06-17"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

render_crosstab <- function(x, ...) {
  for(tabs in x) {
    cat(knitr::knit_expand(text="{{ tabs }}"))
  }
}
```

```{r cars, render=render_crosstab, results='asis'}
library(flextable)
lapply(c('am', 'vs', 'cyl'), function(col) proc_freq(mtcars, col))
```
````

[image: flextables]

### Old Answer

---

You can try as follows,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
date: "2023-06-17"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
library(flextable)
proc_tabs <- lapply(c('am', 'vs'), function(col) proc_freq(mtcars, col))
proc_tabs[[1]]
proc_tabs[[2]]
```
````

Comment: Check the updated answer. Thanks to the detailed answer of  @DavidGohel.